# How to actually implement drag'n'drop in Javascript / Metro-UI under Windows 8

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Somehow I must've missed the proper documentation for something as simple as this. Searching via Google does not exactly yield useful results either.

So, here's what I want to do: Draw a rectangle (div), make it draggable and drop it somewhere else, with a proper validation that the drop point is an actually valid one.

How would I go about doing that with the tools provided by the Visual Studio 11 Beta?

All I've found so far is the onDragging-Event which is not really helpful due to the scarcity of information provided.

Code sample would be great, I could also live with a link to some blog or such.

Edit: Drag and drop through touchscreen input, that is, not through the "normal" mouse interaction.

Comment: I don't know the implications of windows-8/metro-ui, but this is a good starting point: http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx

Comment: See my comment below. Setting draggable=true only works when you're using a mouse-like pointer. It does not work with touchscreen-based input.

Comment: You'll have to watch for touch events instead of mouse: touchstart, touchmove, touchend. Also, you should add a listener on the body and preventDefault() so the whole thing doesn't move

Comment: Uh, just noticed that your example is not HTML5. I actually wanted to get around the whole mess of having to program a homebrewed drag'n'drop solution. Because that's what Luke Breuer is basically doing. I mean, the article is from 2006 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got a reply from a Microsoft employee: It's a bug:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/88cfb689-2e38-417c-a2be-9682f1a23ae4/

So, until that bug is fixed, it seems you really have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

The following link a walkthrough of HTML5 drag/drop in IE10 from the IE blog. IE10 is the engine for Windows Web Apps so this will work in your Windows 8 app.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/27/html5-drag-and-drop-in-ie10-ppb2.aspx

Comment: Just tried that. With IE10 the FridgeMagnets demo does not work in touchscreen mode (stylus and mouse work as advertised). You cannot drag the elements, instead any drag movement will scroll the screen. Similarly, a Metro-App solely consisting of a <div draggable="true"> will not actually yield a draggable div.

Answer (score 0):

Up until and including the beta (CP) we were able to use the dragstart, drag, dragend events even for touch input in Metro. In the newer builds this has stopped working (events don't fire anymore) and it looks like we'll have to switch to MSPointerMove et al. for handling touch-dragging.
From a few samples I created it seems that standalone IE has never supported dragstart, drag and dragend for touch - in other words touch drag works in my sample inside beta Metro, but same file doesn't work inside normal IE there.

Re the answer from Microsoft employee mentioned below, I believe that bug is unrelated to the issue of touch-dragging.